# Angular losing reconnect form in controller after route change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a Controller attached to a route and when the page first loads the form in the template is accessible readily in the controller. The name of the form is form.myForm so in the controller, I can access the form by $scope.form.myform. Everything is peachy except when I navigate away to a different view and come back. When I come back to the same view from another view $scope.form.myForm is no longer connected to the previous form in the $scope. I suspect, I get a whole new scope disconnected from the view. I don't need data to be maintained between these transitions of view, I just need to be able to access the form again and not lose it completely.

How can I reassociate an existing form in one $scope when the routeProvider goes back to that template? Am I violating some priciple of Angular by accessing the form in the template in this manner?

Here is my route definition. The form is in mytemplate.html and the first time the template is loaded, there is no problem with accessing the form in it, but if you navigate to another route and then back, the form can't be accessed in the scope any longer.

First time view is loaded or you refresh browser page.

```
$scope.form.myForm.$valid //evaluates to true
```

On a second visit to the view by route change

```
 $scope.form.myForm.$valid //$scope.form is undefined
```

My route definition

```
routes[ "/myview" ] = {

controller : 'MyController',
templateUrl : 'templates/mytemplate.html',
resolve : {

        ControllerMetaData : function () {
            return {
                    title : "Management",
                    description : "Management"


            }

           }
         }
 };
```

//MyController

```
application.controller('MyController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.form = {}; //If I make this $rootScope, it works on second time back from route change

...

    $scope.pageUp = function(event) {


           //First time through this is all good. after route change and then back to this route, we 
          // no longe have the form anymore 
           if ($scope.form.myForm && $scope.form.myForm.$dirty) 

...
```

Here is the form definition inside mytemplate.html

```
<form name="form.myForm" id="inv" class="forms" role="form"  novalidate>
```

Comment: Let me specify, This works if I put the form in rootscope, but I don't want to put things there if I can help it. Also, i reiterate that I do not care to really keep any of the data that was in the form the last time it was rendered. I just want access to the form object again after the route change and not lose it.

Comment: For now as a workaround, I put $rootScope.form = {}; in my controller and it works just fine. I do not like this but it works until I can get a definitive answer.

Comment: Where and when do you access `$scope.form.myForm.$valid`?

Comment: In a function in the controller $scope context

Comment: I'm afraid we have too little information. `form.myForm` will definitely be created every time the template is compiled. There is a lot of potential reasons for this error. The fact that you can access `$scope.form.myForm.$valid` is no definitive proof that your workaraound actually works, btw. You could be accessing old (i.e. useless) data.

Comment: OK, I posted the controller code with the part where I access the form... Maybe you'll see something that I am obviously missing. I don't care if the data from the last visit is persisted, I just want to be linked back to the form in the template on revisiting the view.

Comment: Where is `LotManagementController` instantiated? Is it the controller defined for the route? An `ngController` outside or inside the template? If inside then inside or outside of `form`?

Comment: that is a typo and should have been MyController. It is the controller for the route... the form is in the template for the route

Comment: There has to be more. I'm not able to reproduce your problem. I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vokU5CyKZIStqvDuq9Pz?p=info). Feel free to adjust the code so it resembles yours. Maybe you have another form or an enclosing form on your page.